# Password text filed in pyqt

Tags: python-2.7

I am new in pyqt4 I want to add a password text field in my design.I can't see any password type text field so there is any way to convert simple text field into password type??

Answer (score 0):

```
editor = QLineEdit()
editor.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
```